# mongodb - Find every document with the same field but different case

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, case-sensitive

I'm having trouble with my database because I have documents representing my users with the field email with different cases (due to the ability to create ghost user, waiting for them to register). When the user registers, I use the lowered version of his email and overwrite the previous entry. The problem is that 'ghost' email has not been lowered.

If Foo@bar.com ghost is created, Foo@bar.com register, he will be known as 'foo@bar.com', so Foo@bar.com will just pollute my database.

I looking for a way in order to find the duplicates entries, remove the irrelevant one (by hand) before I push my fix about case. Ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    "username": { $exists: true }
  }},
  { $project: {
    "username": { "$toLower": [ "$username" ]}
  }},
  { $group: {
    _id: "$username",
    total: { $sum : 1 }
  }},
  { $match: {
    total: { $gte: 2 }
  }},
  { $sort: {
    total: -1
  }}
]);
```

This will find every user with a `username`, make the user names lower case, then group them by `username` and display the *usernames* that have a count greater than 1.

Comment: Works fine, but some Applications (Robo3T in my case) need the aggregation to be inside an array notation `[]`. This would make the query like this: `db.users.aggregate([ ... ])`. Hope this helps, it got me confused.

Answer (score -1):

You can use projection and `toLower` function to achieve what you are looking for. Assuming that your attribute name is `"email"` in your collection document, here is an example of how to achieve this:

```js
db.yourcollection.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    "email": { "$toLower" : [ "$email" ] }
  }},
  { $match: {
    "email": /foo@bar.com/
  }}
]);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank for the answer. The problem is that I have no idea which of the emails are duplicated. I'm not comfortable with $project, I'll read about it. Do you think it's possible to change the $match part to fit my needs?

Comment: before you match it, you will have to convert the attribute to lowerCase so that you can get all the documents. If you dont know which attribute may have duplicate, you can use $OR to include all attributes.